# R: Extract complete cases/included observations from linear model or formula variables

Tags: r, data.table

After running `m1 <- lm(f1, data=DT)` I want to save the observations that are included (akin to "obs <- complete.cases(m1)", but something that works) so that I can run a second regression on the same observations: `m2 <- lm(f2, data=DT[obs])`.

Alternatively, I would like to get the observations that are complete for a given set of variables as defined by a formula object.  Consider this R-like pseudocode:

```
f1 <- as.formula("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3")
f2 <- as.formula("y ~ x1 + x2")
obs <- complete.cases(DT[,list(all.vars(f1)])
m2 <- lm(f2, data=DT[obs])
```

How do I do this? In the first case, `lm` already does the work implicitly; how can I extract it? In the second, `all.vars` returns a character vector; how do I properly create an unquoted list that DT (data.table) will understand?

Comment: `obs <- complete.cases(DT[, c(all.vars(f1)), with = FALSE])`

Comment: This answers my question. Incidentally, `obs <- complete.cases(DT[, all.vars(f1), with = FALSE])` also works since `all.vars` returns a character vector. I did try the `with` flag (`list(f1),with=TRUE`) but that doesn't work.

Comment: Because `list` performs a non standard evaluation within the `data.table` environment which means it receives unquoted variable names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `data.table v1.9.5`, `na.omit` has a `cols` argument.

```
na.omit(DT, cols = all.vars(f))
```

Comment: Yes I think this also answers my question, though I didn't test it. Looks cleaner too. Thanks Arun.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the na.action of your lm() call is the default na.omit, why not just call na.omit on the original data?

```
# create some missing values
mtcars$disp <- ifelse(runif(nrow(mtcars)) > 0.8, NA, mtcars$disp)

# fit model
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

na.omit(mtcars[ , c("mpg", "disp")])
```

Check out the helpfile for na.omit for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this doesn't answer my question. `na.omit(data[subset])` is equivalent to `data[complete.cases(data[subset])]` and is perhaps more concise, but the issue is about creating the subset from formulae (or character vectors via `all.vars(f)`).